# How to load Sequence of images from a video using "generateCGImagesAsynchronously"?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to generate images to a Scroll view (just like when a video starts playing in default ios player).

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let asset :AVAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url as URL)
let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;

var img = UIImage()

assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
let thumbTime: CMTime = asset.duration
let times = thumbTime as NSValue

assetImgGenerate.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: [times], completionHandler: {( requestedTime, image, actualTime,result, error) -> Void in
  img = UIImage(cgImage: image!)
  imageView.image = img
})

scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(imageView.frame.width), height: 0)
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)}
```

this doesn't give any output. How can I generate Images as a sequence to be displayed inside a scroll view?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. You are asking AVAssetGenerator some images at a specific time, but in the block you are always assigning the last one to the image view.
2. Your scrollview (supposing that you set it properly) has the width of the image view, that probably at the time of assign is 0, the height is also set 0.
3. You are probably missing the point that the AVAssetGenerator generate images asynchronously thus the settings to the scrollview are set before the first image is returned inside the block
4. Try everything on paper, how are you supposed to create a sort of continuous images scrollview if you are always setting the same image view? You should probably loop through all the images returned, create an image view for each one of them, position them side-by-side and set the content size accordingly.
   One last gotcha images are quite expensive in memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understood that I need to create image view for each return values and I believe that I need to loop through each value of "times" variable. But How would I do that, I am new at this. Where should I place the loop for execution? Could you please advice me. Thanks in Advance bro.

Comment: It works fine now. I coded, just like you said. I only thing that I was lacking = LOGIC. Boooomm

Comment: But as you said, images are creating a lot of memory here, What Can I do to solve that issue?

Comment: Should I have to change from scroll view to collectionView??? It will make a difference right.

Comment: Hi @fAiSaL depends, of course a collection view guarantees that the images shown in the cell are the only images loaded, but only if you load them at the appropriate time. the other thing that you can do is size the images at the exact size that you need. There is `maximumSize` in AVAssetImageCreator property. My suggestion is to save them in a temp directory, and create UIImage instances only when you need and pass them to a collection view cell.